# Wi-fi hard blocked in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, ralink

after some update approximately a year ago, my wi-fi became hard-blocked. I've tried countless tutorials solving similar problem but nothing has helped me, so I'm finally desperate enough to ask by myself.
I have HP Pavilion with Ubuntu 16.04 and my network controller is

```
Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

- Hardware button only changes if the wi-fi is soft-blocked. (edit: now my hardwave switch doesn't change anything)
- `rfkill unblock all` doesn't work.
- `sudo ifconfig RT3290 up` tells me, that this module is not found (I've tried even different versions of name, but it's possible, that I'm just not able to find a right name of my controller)

Most of my attempts was like a six months ago, so I don't even remember what I've tried.
With Windows (I have dual-boot), wifi is working ok.

Can you please help me?

Edit 7.9.: I've reinstalled Ubuntu and it's still not working. Wifi is hard-blocked, flight mode is on and I can't turn it off, because hardware switch doesn't work (only in Ubuntu. In Windows, wifi and hardware switch are ok)

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issues and use the following 3 commands to fix it.

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service 
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

I dont remember where I found it as I have been using these commands for a while. Let me know it helps or if you have any queries.

Comment: Do I have to change 'wlan0' with something? Because result with this was
'wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device'

Comment: Yes. Can you post the output for 'iwconfig'. You will have to select your own wifi using this

Comment: Output for 'iwconfig':
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

Comment: With 'sudo ifconfig wlo1 up' I got 'SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill'

Answer (score 0):

Few days back i face the same issue with my Toshiba satellite laptop,what i found the solution is I just remove my battery and replug it and restart after that the problem get solve.
It works for my laptop try for your but I don't give guarantee of that.

Comment: Thank you! My hardware switch is now OK, but sadly it again only changes if the wifi is soft-blocked - so wifi is still disabled/ hard-blocked.